# Ubuntu with Mac Keyboard: Keyboard shortcut to select till end of line

Tags: shortcut-keys, macbook-pro

What's the keyboard shortcut to select till the end of line when running Ubuntu with Mac keyboard. (Similar to `shift`+ `command` + `->` on mac)?

Comment: Won't that be specific to the application (e.g., editor) you are using?

Answer (score 0):

With most apps I use from my Macbook Pro running Ubuntu 20.04 (e.g., Visual Studio Code, Chromium, etc.) I can get the select to continue to the end of the line using:

[Shift] + [Fn] + [Right Arrow]